# Need a single installer for a VSTO 4.0 Outlook Add-in which includes all prerequisites

Tags: .net, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook add-in written by someone else using VSTO 4.0.

There are the following prerequisites:

- .NET 4 Framework
- Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies
- VSTO 4.0 Runtime

I have created a VS2010 Setup project which succesfully uses launch conditions to search for these prereqs. For .NET 4, it will automatically install it for the user if it is missing. However, the other requirements are not installed automaically. The best I have managed is for the installer to prompt the user asking if they want to download the prereq now, 'yes' or 'no' (I have used the 'Install Url' property of the launch condition to take them to the correct location). After the user has manually installed them they need to run our add-in installer again.

What I am looking for is a way for my installer to automatically install the missing prereqs without pausing the installation, and without the user having to take uneccessary steps. Whether this means including the prereqs in the installer file somehow or getting the installer to do the download work.

There is also a concern that because I have manually entered the Install url, it may become invalid at some point. Is there a more standardised way of doing this sort of thing that I am missing?

The app is not for internal use and we don't run IIS for deployemnet etc, out systems are mostly linux based. So we ideally want a single installer wuch as an MSI.

Any suggestions most welcomed.

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the properties of the setup project, click the prerequisites and choose "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application". This option builds your MSI with all the prerequisites required. But still the user has to click "I Agree" button for accepting T&C's when they install dot net framework.

Or you could try silent install of MSI from command line.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems to have done the trick! You've saved me a lot of time there so thanks.

Comment: The only problem with this is that, because the .NET framework is a prerequisite, it means i need to distribute this with everything else. This means it ends up being around 63 MB in total. If I was able to distribute the installer wihout that it would be much smaller as the other prerequisities are small in comparison.

Comment: ...Being as my previous installer successfully downloaded and installed the .NET framework automatically (it was the only prereq that I was able to do this with) i wondered if I could somehow set it so that .NET is downloaded from the website, but the other prereqs are installed from the current folder. I tried setting the install URL for the launch conditions but if I remove the .NET folder from the installer path it gives me an error.

Comment: If you are concerned about the size of the setup folder, try the third option "Download prerequisites from the following location" and place the prerequisites in the shared folder with access to everyone.

Comment: Thanks. But we this is for external distribution so the shared folder is not really an option.

Comment: Then you got only two option wither download from vendor website during install or create MSI with all the prerequisites.